# Nusach Ashkenaz in Israel and Abroad

Tags: sources-mekorot, prayer-book, mesorah-tradition, spelling-variants

Over the years, I've noticed a number of differences between Ashkenaz siddurim published in Israel and those published outside of Israel. These differences include (but are not limited to):

- Order of Birchot HaShachar (asher yatzar and birchot haTorah before/after Yigdal and Adon Olam)
- changes from ךָ- to הַּ-, particularly in Birkat Hashannim (Amidah)
- assorted word changes
- Israeli siddurim will often change spellings from the chaser to the maleh
- textual sources for piyutim (Yedid Nefesh is a prime example, the author's manuscript is different from the version which will be found in ArtScroll or Birnbaum)

What is the rationale for these changes and how far back do they date relative to their non-Israeli counterparts?

Comment: Can you name any other examples of 2?

Comment: First point of research would be to see if the Israeli versions match up with the opinions of the Vilna Gaon.

Comment: @DoubleAA, not off hand, but I often use a Rinat Yisrael Ashkenaz on weekdays, so I assume I'll find more if I look. In the meantime, I'll remove the word numerous.

Comment: @user6591, I assume that some of the changes relate to the opinions of the Gr"a, although I don't have his opinions in accessible language or his siddur on hand.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to changes from ךָ- to הַּ-, particularly in Birkat Hashannim (Amidah)

I assume that you are referring to the difference between 1- שבעינו מטובך vs. 2 - שבעינו מטובה.

The 1st one means "Your goodness" is said outside Israel because we are referring to G-d's general goodness in blessing the land of Israel.

The 2nd version said in Israel, means "her goodness" referring to the land of Israel (אדמה is a fem. word), which you are in, now. Thus, in Israel, it is more "personal" as we ask G-d to bless us with the land's goodness, because we benefit directly.

It is similar to the change I have seen regarding the ending of the Bracha made after eating one of the 7 species fruits. In Israel, some say על פריה.

Comment: I knew about the definitions, however I still don't know the rationale.